# Parity Error: It doesn't connect to Volta testnetwork of EWF

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, energy, parity-io

I'm setting up a local node using parity. Whenever I try to connect the client to Volta though as shown [here](https://energyweb.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/EWF/pages/703103027/Volta+Installing+the+Client), it just throws an error. The error is always the same: ***Spec json is invalid: missing field `eip1108_transition_base` at line 142 column 21***

I have tried to connect with different combinations, like:

```
parity --chain "Volta.json",

parity --chain "Volta.json" --jsonrpc-cors https://volta-rpc.energyweb.org,

parity --chain Volta.json --jsonrpc-cors http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

I expected that the parity client should connect to Volta testnetwork as node. So how can I solve this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parity was updated to include EIP1108 modifications. The eip1108_transition_base and eip1108_transition_pair fields are declared as mandatory. Look at the builtin alt_bn128 functions in the following json to correct the error:

https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/blob/61a7c30ed5a093c7c2a26a93aeb1ed5fda3cb017/ethcore/res/ethereum/volta.json

Note that Istanbul fork mods include blake2_f builtin now too.